# One AlertDialog, Used in Multi Activities?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have an AlertDialog that needs to be used in several Activities. How can I accomplish this with its own Class? Thank-you for your help!~!

I tried the following and acces it in an Activity w:

```
Alerts.sdCardMissing();
```

The class I 'tried' to create:

```
public class Alerts {

public static void sdCardMissing() {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(null).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("External Storage State");
    alertDialog
            .setMessage("Your SD-Card is not mounted!  If the device is plugged into a computer via the USB, please disconect the device.");
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // this.finish();
        }
    });
    // alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try...

```
public class Alerts {
    public static void sdCardMissing(Context context) {
        // Pass context to AlertDialog.Builder
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
        ...
    }
}
```

Then call it from the Activity with...

```
// Pass the Activity context as 'this'
Alerts.sdCardMissing(this);
```

Comment: Thnx @MisterSquonk!! That did it.

Comment: @camelCaser: Glad to be of help.

Comment: You know those days where you overthink a problem only to realize that the answer is this simple? <3 SOF

Comment: @Jacksonkr : Oh...I have those days quite often. :D